# Problem in using Solr WordDelimiterFilter

Tags: filter, lucene, solr, tokenize, analyzer

I am doing some test using WordDelimiterFilter in Solr  but it doesn't preserve the protected list of words which I pass to it. Would you please inspect the code and the output example and suggest which part is missing or used badly?

with running this code:

```
private static Analyzer getWordDelimiterAnalyzer() {
    return new Analyzer() {
        @Override
        public TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
            TokenStream stream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_32, reader);
            WordDelimiterFilterFactory wordDelimiterFilterFactory = new WordDelimiterFilterFactory();
            HashMap<String, String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();
            args.put("generateWordParts", "1");
            args.put("generateNumberParts", "1");
            args.put("catenateWords", "1");
            args.put("catenateNumbers", "1");
            args.put("catenateAll", "0");
            args.put("luceneMatchVersion", Version.LUCENE_32.name());
            args.put("language", "English");
            args.put("protected", "protected.txt");
            wordDelimiterFilterFactory.init(args);
            ResourceLoader loader = new SolrResourceLoader(null, null);
            wordDelimiterFilterFactory.inform(loader);
            /*List<String> protectedWords = new ArrayList<String>();
            protectedWords.add("good bye");
            protectedWords.add("hello world");
            wordDelimiterFilterFactory.inform(new LinesMockSolrResourceLoader(protectedWords));
            */
            return wordDelimiterFilterFactory.create(stream);
        }
    };
}
```

### input text:

### hello world

### good bye

### what is your plan for future?

---

### protected strings:

### good bye

### hello world

---

### output:

### (hello,startOffset=0,endOffset=5,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (world,startOffset=6,endOffset=11,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (good,startOffset=12,endOffset=16,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (bye,startOffset=17,endOffset=20,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (what,startOffset=21,endOffset=25,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (is,startOffset=26,endOffset=28,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (your,startOffset=29,endOffset=33,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (plan,startOffset=34,endOffset=38,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (for,startOffset=39,endOffset=42,positionIncrement=1,type=)

### (future,startOffset=43,endOffset=49,positionIncrement=1,type=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a standard tokenizer which at least tokenizes on a whitespace level so you will always have "hello world" be split to "hello" and "world".

```
TokenStream stream = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_32, reader);
```

See Lucene Documentation:

> public final class StandardTokenizer extends Tokenizer
>
> A grammar-based tokenizer constructed with JFlex
>
> This should be a good tokenizer for most European-language documents:
>
> Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuation.
>   However, a dot that's not followed by whitespace is considered part of
>   a token.
>
> Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token, in
>   which case the whole token is interpreted as a product number and is
>   not split.
>
> Recognizes email addresses and internet hostnames as one token.

The word delimiter protected word list is meant for something like:

- ISBN2345677 to be split in ISBN 2345677
- text2html not to be split in text 2 html (because text2html was added to protected words)

If you really want to do something like you mentioned you may use the **KeywordTokenizer**. But you have to do the complete splitting by yourself.

Comment: thank you very much, it seems I've demanded a different functionality from what WordDelimiterFilter is expected to do. KeywordTokenizer emit whole the text as a single token. It is not what I want, Is there any filter ot tokenizer which would protect keywords containing whitespaces from splitting?

Comment: You may have a look at `CommonGramsFilterFactor`.